# Sorting multiple columns using larger Reference list

Tags: r, sorting, matching

> This is my sample df with 486 columns

```
Source          Target Value    Category_links
ANACANTHOBATIDAELC  9   Least Concerned 
ARHYNCHOBATIDAE DD  1   Data Deficient
ARHYNCHOBATIDAE LC  36  Least Concerned 
ARHYNCHOBATIDAE NT  9   Near Threatened 
ARHYNCHOBATIDAE VU  3   Vulnerable  
ARHYNCHOBATIDAE EN  3   Endangered
ARHYNCHOBATIDAE CR  2   Critically Endangered   
CARCHARHINIDAE  NT  2   Near Threatened 
CARCHARHINIDAE  VU  7   Vulnerable
```

This is my sample reference list 57 columns

```
-----------------------
       Family
-----------------------
1  |    Heterodontidae|
2  ||Chlamydoselachidae|
3  |       Hexanchidae|
4  |    Rhincodontidae|
5  |     Orectolobidae|
6  |    Odontaspididae|
7  |          Lamnidae|
8  |         Alopiidae|
9  |    Hemiscylliidae|
10 |    Brachaeluridae|
11 |   Stegostomatidae|
12 |Ginglymostomatidae|
13 |     Megachasmidae|
14 |    Scyliorhinidae|
15 |    Carcharhinidae|
16 |        Sphyrnidae|
17 |         Triakidae|
18 |     Proscylliidae|
19 |    Hemigaleidae|
20 |        Squalidae|
21 |   Pristiophoridae|
```

I want to sort the 'Source' column in the df as in the order of the 'Family' in the reference list, avoiding any extra 'Family' given in the reference list

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: When providing a sample of your data, use `dput` to create reproducible data instead a print out from the console

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

sample_df |> 
  arrange(ordered(source, levels = reference_list))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.